# Apache rewrite engine, get subdomain and path after it

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the basic code to rewrite a subdomain to another page. But how do I use this to get the path of the directory specified within it and pass it to my script as well as the subdomain itself?

Current code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)(\.example\.com)$
RewriteRule ^$ handle.php [L]
```

I'd like to provide handle.php with the file path specified after **.example.com* and also the subdomain name in the form *handle.php?path=x&subdomain=y*.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access that information with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (does also contain the query):

```
$path = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$subdomain = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L]
```

- `%1` is a subdomain name
- `$1` is a request

Comment: This doesn't work. I get an Internal Server Error when adding the /$1. I can have %1 or $1 by itself, but when both are together it crashes.

Comment: I believe that the reason this crashes is it causes an infinite loop.